# Does revolving about different lines(washer method) give us different volumes?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, contour-integration

[Here's a graph for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbBsN.png)Find the volume of the figure created by two curves y=x^2, y=x^3, revolved about x=1.(Washer) While I do understand the working of this problem, are we not supposed to get the same answer when we revolve it about x=0? The figures are symmetric and if I take clay and create molds for these two figures, and fill water in these molds, ideally they should be having the same quantity of water even if it's differently spread out.(Different surface areas but same volume).

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Are you rotating the area enclosed between the two curves for x from 0 to 1? The rotation axis will matter - if you take an area and rotate it around a large radius you will get a larger volume than if you rotate it about a small one.

Comment: The actual questions says rotate it about x=1, but we tried rotating it about x=0. Ideally even if the cross sections and surface areas are different, the volume should be the same because they're both inverted and modified versions of each other. The difference in the volumes calculated both ways is about 0.11, and I'm interested in knowing where this error is from.

Comment: Again, is volume the space taken up by the shape, or is it a measure of how much a shape can hold? If the first one is the case, then even if its different spread out, the volume of the unit, in its units, must be the same?

Comment: Possibly helpful (Pappus's Theorem), specifically "The second Theorem" on this page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem. A volume of revolution is equal to the area of the region revolved times the distance travelled by the centroid of the region.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you get the same answer? Consider the square whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. If you rotate it around the line $x=1$, you get a cylinder whose volume is $\pi\times1^2\times1=\pi$. But if you rotate it around the line $x=2$, you get a hollow cylinder whose volume is$$\pi\times2^2\times1-\pi\times1^2\times1=3\pi.$$

Comment: What if you rotate it around x=1? In my question, even if the cross section and surface areas of the figures are different, ideally, the volume should be the same cause it's within x=1, and one figure is an inverted and modified version of the other.

Comment: In my answer, I did consider the rotation around $x=1$. So, I don't understand your comment.